# Different classification loss for K-nearest neighbours

Tags: self-study, classification, loss-functions

Suppose we have a general classification loss instead of a 0-1 loss. How can we modify k-NN to accommodate such a loss function?

---

I thought about using a weighted loss matrix where
 $L(i,j)=0$ when $i=j$
$L(i,j)=p$ when $i \neq j$ where $p$ is the misclassification error.
 Basically not all errors are the same for me. Some are more valuable to miss than the others. Can this be a possible explanation for the above question?